# jsconfig.json affects vscode's prompt for pinia method

Tags: vscode-jsconfig

jsconfig.json affects vscode's prompt for pinia method

`jsconfig.json` file

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

when this file exist project root path, vscode cannot perform syntax association.

For example, enter mapAction to automatically import for this method.

remode the `jsconfig.json` file, it's work.

Anyhelp Thinks